# In CKEditor, how can I add a "text" label to a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

```
editor.ui.addButton( 'ImageUpload',{
                label: 'Upload Image',
                command: 'popup_image_uploader',
                icon: this.path + 'images/icon.png'
            });
```

That's my current code right now. When you load the page, you only see the icon.

But if you go to the demo [here](http://ckeditor.com/demo), you'll see that "Source" is a text.  I want to add the word "Upload Image" next to the icon.

Comment: I html you'd put the text in between the button tags `<button>Button text</button>`. Not sure about how to do that in CKEditor though.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The label for CKeditor toolbar buttons have a class **.cke_label** which has by default `display:none` so the buttons are icon-only:

```
.cke_skin_kama .cke_button .cke_label {
    ...
    display: none;
    ...
}
```

Like for the *Source* button, you have to use CSS to show your label.

*Normally* when creating the button CKeditor add a class like `.cke_button_CMDNAMEHERE` where *CMDNAMEHERE* being the name of your command. So you'll have:

```
.cke_skin_kama .cke_button_CMDNAMEHERE .cke_label {
   display: inline;
}
```

Check the html source to see the exact name of the added class and make your CSS rule accordingly.

Comment: In the ckeditor folder I guess. But you shouldn't edit this file otherwise it will not work anymore if you update you ckeditor installation and forget to change again the css. Override this in your website's css.

Comment: I found the file located in ckeditor/skin/kama/editor.css . After edit the file, it's worked. But i agree to add my own css instead, haha. BTW thank you so much Didier. ^^

Comment: If you just want the label for the image button, you can use `.cke_skin_kama .cke_button .cke_button_image .cke_label { display: inline-block; }`

Comment: Note that with CKEditor 4 you need to remove the space between the classes, for the Mono Theme / Image button I used: `.cke_button_label.cke_button__image_label { display:inline-block !important; }`

Comment: As in _Echt Einfach TV_'s comment and in other answers here, for CKEditor 4 you actually need **two underscores** before `CMDNAMEHERE`. So `cke_button__source`, not `cke_button_source` for example.

Answer (score 3):

another solution would be to just use the css ":before" or ":after" pseudo class to add some custom content before / after the buttons.

for example, customizing the "link" button:

create some space (depends on length of content):

```
.cke_button_icon.cke_button__link_icon {
padding-right: 25px;
}
```

add content:

```
.cke_button_icon.cke_button__link_icon:after {
content: "Link";
position: relative;
left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.cke_button_label.cke_button__CMDNAMEHERE{
   display: inline;
}
```

will work for all skins, unlike the answer above(note the double underscore between buttons and CMDNAMEHERE)

you can place it anywhere in your own css

Comment: For ckeditor 4 you have to use:
.cke_button_label.cke_button__CMDNAMEHERE_label{
   display: inline;
}

Answer (score 0):

In the current ckeditor (4.6.x) the answers above do not work for me.

I dug around in ckeditor/skins/moono-list/editor.css and did a search for "source" to find how they did the Source button which has text. I found this:

```
.cke_button__source_label,
.cke_button__sourcedialog_label
{
    display:inline
}
```

Notice that there are TWO underscores here before the name of your custom button. When I tried with only one underscore it did not work.

Anyway you would replace "source" or "sourcedialog" above with whatever you want and add that to your own css file.

Additionally, it seems to only work for button names that are entirely *lowercase*.