# Remove "Source" from CKEditor UI Source Dialog plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using CKEditor (v4.7.0 - custom build) and I have added the Source Dialog plugin (http://ckeditor.com/addon/sourcedialog).

What is the best way remove the word "Source" from the toolbar UI?

e.g. from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I'm using the jQuery adaptor and initialising the editor like this:

```
$(el).ckeditor({
    removePlugins: 'maximize,floatingspace,resize',
    extraPlugins: 'autogrow,sharedspace,sourcedialog',
    autoGrow_onStartup: true,
    toolbarGroups: { name: 'main', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools', 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing', 'clipboard', 'undo', 'forms', 'links', 'insert', 'basicstyles', 'cleanup', 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph', 'styles', 'tools', 'colors' ] },
    autoGrow_maxHeight: 800,
    sharedSpaces: {
        top: 'editorActions',
        bottom: 'editorFooter'
    },
    on: {
        blur: function(evt) {
            // blur functions
        },
        instanceReady: function (evt) {
            // initial functions
        },
        change: function(evt) {
            // save functions
        }
    }
});
```

Currently I am simply deleting the text by targeting the element on load.

```
$('#cke_[id]_label').html('&nbsp;');
```

But this feels somewhat hacktastic and I'd like to not load it rather than removing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide the label and leave only the icon with CSS:

```
.cke_button__source_label {
    display: none !important;
}
```

or

```
.cke_button_label.cke_button__source_label {
    display: none;
}
```

See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8487229/4708866

Answer (score -1):

Just include this line in your config.js

```
config.removeButtons = 'Source';
```

or from the replace method as follows:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('exampleEditor1', {
   removeButtons: 'Source',
   extraPlugins: 'sourcedialog'
});
```

Comment: This removes the whole button, not just the label.